# NetBeans: Make Find/Replace field longer?

Tags: netbeans

I can't find an option to make the text display for Find/Replace longer in NetBeans 8.2 on Windows.

On a 2560x1600 monitor I could easily make the text box 6 times longer if possible without any issues. Is this possible in the options that I'm somehow missing? Or a plugin?

[image: NetBeans Find/Replace UI]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly perfect, as I'd rather extend the width of the Find/Replace bottom bar, but I can get a bigger Find/Replace by doing "Replace in Projects" (Control-Shift-H).